# Very specific question to mouse-movement and coordinate translation (C# / Win-Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse, coordinate-systems

I'm working on a small painting program in which I can use the mouse to move/resize the shapes with handles on the corners. This already works well, except when the shape is **rotated**.

I need a translation between X- and Y-Coordinates. I've tried some sine/cosine calculations, but without success. Either I have fundamental errors in my formulas or the changes for X/Y in the MouseMove event are too small for this calculation.

Does anyone have experience with this topic or perhaps a few good links (maybe with examples)?

Thx in advance, Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using angles as much as possible, prefer to use *transforms*, i.e. matrices.

One example of this would be [system.numerics.matrix3x2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix3x2.createrotation?view=net-6.0), this has methods to create transforms from angles, translations, scaling etc. Some important properties of matrices is that you can combine them and invert them. In addition to simply using them to transform a point.

It is also often useful to draw a matrix to visualize the transform, i.e. multiply a zero-vector, the x unit vector and y unit vector with the matrix, and draw some lines between these points, that should give you a good visualization of what the transform does.

While not absolutely required, some [linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra) knowledge is very useful when doing things like this.

Comment: Thank you for the tip with the matrix. Currently I use a matrices for my "viewport" to move it around and of course for translating/rotating the shapes. However, it never occurred to me to use them for mouse movements as well.

Unfortunately I'm very busy at the moment and I can't work on this "hobby-project" ;-)
I'll tell, if I tried it out. Greats Peter.

Comment: You gave me the perfect tip and I solved my problem with a matrix transformation. 

Although the MouseMove-Event raises movements by only 1 pixel, the matrix (which works with float values of course) can be used with enough accuracy. After thinking about the unit circle with sin/cos for about one hour, I figured out, why X/Y coordinates must be changed, before executing the matrix-rotation. Finally the solution is pretty simple :-)